# Lower Bound on Product of $L^p$-norms

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, lp-spaces

Is there an established way to get a single $L^p$-norm that bounds from below
$$\int |f|^p \int |f|^q\;?$$

Comment: How do you pass from individual exponents $p$ and $p'$ to the single exponent $\min(p',p)$?

Comment: I assume that each of the terms in the original product are $\ge 1$ allowing me to take the minimum exponent. This of course isn’t always the case but for where this problem came from, it was the case.

Comment: OK, you even state that in the OP. I read right past it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ belongs to both $L^p$ and $L^q$ then it belongs to every $L^r$ with $r$ in between $p$ and $q$. The standard estimate uses Holder's inequality: you can interpolate $r = tp + (1-t)q$ with $0 < t < 1$ and use the conjugate exponents $\dfrac 1t$, $\dfrac 1{1-t}$ to find
$$\int |f|^r = \int |f|^{tp}|f|^{(1-t)q} \le \left( \int |f|^p \right)^t \left( \int |f|^q \right)^{1-t}.$$
To get the product of the integrals on the right you would require $t = \frac 12$ and so $$\left( \int |f|^{(p+q)/2} \right)^2 \le \int |f|^p \int |f|^q.$$

Comment: This works great. If we assume that $|f|\ge 1$ on $\text{supp}(f)$ so that $\int |f|^p$ is increasing in $p$, is there any way to increase the exponent past $(p+q)/2$ if we assume that $|f|$ isn't constant on $\text{supp}(f)$ (and thus no equality by Holder)?

Comment: @WillFisher Offhand I'm not sure. Do you want to preserve the product of $\|f\|_p^p$ and $\|f\|_q^q$ in the upper bound, or can they be raised to different exponents? I expect scaling considerations will rule out inequalities with incorrect exponents.

Comment: Ideally the same, but it could also be exponents that sum to $1$. My guess however is that we could have something like $$\Big(\int|f|^{(p+q)/2+\epsilon}\Big)^2\le \int |f|^p\int |f|^q$$ where $\epsilon$ depends on $$\int_{\text{supp}(f)} (\sup |f| - |f|)$$ since this measures in a sense the degree to which Holder fails to be an equality.

Comment: I see, so the exponent would somehow depend on $f$. I'll keep it in mind.